# Migrate databases across Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, azure-sql-managed-instance

I would like to migrate databases from one Azure SQL Managed instance to another and from Azure SQL Managed instance to Azure SQL DB. What is the best approach for it with minimum downtime for 5TB database?

I have checked a few approaches like:

Data migration service- Doesn't support Azure Managed Instance as source.

Failover group- It doesn't support same region secondary.

Copy/Move- This cannot be used as the current databases are in failover group.

Is there any other way to migrate with minimum downtime?

Thanks!

Comment: The only other methods I have used is copying the database using bacpacs and Storage Accounts or using Backups/Restore. Both are time-consuming tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/replication-transactional-overview?view=azuresql) for this.

Comment: Hi David, thanks, transactional replication will help replicating the databases across managed instance and azure SQL DB but i am worries about the additional load it will generate on the production instance.

Comment: Yes.  The resource consumption is mostly on the instance hosting the distribution database which can be remote.